# How to change track width in Altium for already placed tracks

Tags: altium, impedance-matching, length-matching

I have a PCB with 8 layers and hundreds of tracks on different layers that already placed and length matched. I have to change again the track width to achieve the 50 Ohm impedance again because we have changed the stack up.

I can’t select all lines at once and change the track as normally done because some parts of generated impedance matching tracks are also selected and don’t let me using the PCB filter to change all tracks at once!

This will take a lot of hours now if I have to delete each impedance matching on each track and then change the width then match the impedance again.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Use the PCBA filter to use rule based selection.

Comment: What was the reason to change the stack up?

Comment: What exactly does this mean -- "because some parts of generated impedance matching tracks are also selected and don’t let me using the PCB filter to change all tracks at once"? Is there an error message?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean rule based selection? and "i mean some parts of generated.." because when i select the track and press Tab or using PCB filter the matched lenght is not of type track but of type others. So you can't select a track that has some matched lenght and change it width with one click. And we have changed the stack up because the we have to manufacture the board by other place.

Comment: I would really appreciate you answer if you explain as answer exactly how to use rule-based filter.
I have used hundred of times the pcb filter and I know it good but I didn’t understand what do you mean.

Comment: Another option is to note/specify the impedance value for the nets, and then let the board house adjust the PCB per the actual stackup and dielectric constant that they have available to create the trace impedance that you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to get the selection you want:

### Properties Filter

- Use `tab` to select all of the components of the net, as you mentioned in your comment
- Your properties box will appear as below. Click the filter icon in the top-right corner:
  [image]
- Unselect everything except for "Tracks". You will then be able to change those track properties as normal:
  [image]

### Find Similar Objects

- Select one section of the track you want to change. Right-click on it and then choose "Find Similar Objects":
  [image]
- Set Layer, Net, Width, etc as appropriate to select all objects that match the portion of the track you selected
  [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but if I do this i can change only the the width of track but i have again then to delete the matched lenght object then do the lengh matching again because using the changing the width in the properties will not effect the matched part.

Comment: After you have changed the track width, select track+match length object using Tab again. Then, select Route->Retrace Selected    https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/post-route-glossing-and-retracing-ad

Comment: Thank you very much it works!